# Magento category dropdown menu - sub menu to be in 2 columns

Tags: magento, menu, drop-down-menu

I using Magento Community Edition v1.5.

By default all sub categories appear one after the other (1 column) under main category on mouse over e.g Main category is Apparel, Sub category will display Shirts, Pants etc in 1 column.

I would like to display sub-categories in 2 or 3 columns on mouse over main category. Doesn't allow me to post sample screenshort but I hope my question is clear. Thank you.

Comment: Sketch it if you can't post ss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this extension may be this can fulfil your requirments

http://web-experiment.info/webandpeople-custom-menu-extension.html

cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks Jitendra. I couldn't installed that extension through Magento Connect or upload zip file. I contacted the developer to find out how to install the extension. I got a reply from the developer **You need to copy files right to the magento dir.
Not sure where it goes exactly.** Exact reply from the developer!

Comment: Hi, extract the zip file copy app folder from extension and paste it on your magento app folder same as copy sking folder and paste it on your magento installation skin folder thats it for more help you can ping me on my skype jeet.magentoconnect